# Is it possible to speed up this MATLAB script?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

I've encountered some performance problems thus I want to speed up those running-slow scripts. But I have no more ideas on how to speed up them. Because I found I was often blocked with the indices. I found the abstract thinking is very difficult for me.

The script is

```
    tic,
    n = 1000;
    d = 500;
    X = rand(n, d);
    R = rand(n, n);
    F = zeros(d, d);
    for i=1:n
        for j=1:n
           F = F + R(i,j)* ((X(i,:)-X(j,:))' * (X(i,:)-X(j,:)));
        end
    end
    toc
```

Comment: Hm. This looks so familiar. What exactly are you implementing? Maybe we can use some math to speed things up even more.

Comment: Hi, @knedlsepp, I'm trying to implement this paper [http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2566-neighbourhood-components-analysis.pdf].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Discussion & Solution Codes

Few approaches with `bsxfun` could be suggested here. Also, read on to see how one can get **`30x+`** speedup on a problem like this!

**Approach #1 (Naive vectorized approach)**

To accommodate the two operations of subtractions between rows of `X` and then the subsequent element-wise multiplications between them, a naive `bsxfun` based approach would lead to a 4D intermediate array which would correspond to `((X(i,:)-X(j,:))' * (X(i,:)-X(j,:)))`. After that, one needs to multiply `R` to have the final output `F`. This is implemented as shown next -

```
v1 = bsxfun(@minus,X,permute(X,[3 2 1]));
v2 = bsxfun(@times,permute(v1,[1 3 2]),permute(v1,[1 3 4 2]));
F = reshape(R(:).'*reshape(v2,[],d^2),d,[]);
```

**Approach #2 (Not-so-naive vectorized approach)**

The earlier mentioned approach goes into 4D which could slow down things. So, instead you can keep the intermediate data until 3D by reshaping. This is listed next -

```
sub1 = bsxfun(@minus,X,permute(X,[3 2 1]));
sub1_2d = reshape(permute(sub1,[1 3 2]),n^2,[])
mult1 = bsxfun(@times,sub1_2d,permute(sub1_2d,[1 3 2]))
F = reshape(R(:).'*reshape(mult1,[],d^2),d,[])
```

**Approach #3 (Hybrid approach)**

Now, you can make a hybrid approach based on *Approach #2* (`vectorized subtractions` + `loopy multiplications`). Benefit of this approach would be that it uses the `fast matrix multiplication` to perform the  multiplications and reduces the complexity to O(n) from the earlier O(n^2) and this should make it much more efficient. Thanks to @Dev-iL, for suggesting this idea! Here's the code -

```
sub1 = bsxfun(@minus,X,permute(X,[3 2 1]));
sub1 = bsxfun(@times,sub1,permute(sqrt(R),[1 3 2]));

F = zeros(d);
for k = 1:size(sub1,3)
    blk = sub1(:,:,k);    
    F = F + blk.'*blk;
end
```

---

### Benchmarking

**Benchmarking code comparing the original approach against *Approach #3***

```
%// Parameters
n = 500;
d = 250;
X = rand(n, d);
R = rand(n, n);

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:100000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

disp('------------------------------ With Original Approach')
tic
F1 = zeros(d, d);
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        F1 = F1 + R(i,j)*((X(i,:)-X(j,:))' * (X(i,:)-X(j,:)));
    end
end
toc, clear F1 i j

disp('------------------------------ With Proposed Approach #3')
tic
sub1 = bsxfun(@minus,X,permute(X,[3 2 1]));
sub1 = bsxfun(@times,sub1,permute(sqrt(R),[1 3 2]));

F = zeros(d);
for k = 1:size(sub1,3)
    blk = sub1(:,:,k);    
    F = F + blk.'*blk;
end
toc
```

**Runtime results**

```
------------------------------ With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 29.728571 seconds.
------------------------------ With Proposed Approach #3
Elapsed time is 0.839726 seconds.
```

So, who's ready for a **30x+** speedup!?

Comment: Hi, @Divakar, thank you very much! I've tested your code on my computer, there is the memory problem in the computation of `v2`. Could you help improve it, please? I wonder if this operation should be using `mex` code.

Comment: @mining Yeah, not surprised really because with such datasizes `v2` would end up as `1000 x 1000 x 500 x 500` which is plain huge! I think if you are really dealing with datasizes, stick with you for-loop!

Comment: yes, the `n`  is the number of samples and `d` is the dimension of features. If the whole loop costs too much memory, I wonder if we could just speed the inner loop to decrease the memory and at the same time improve some performance?

Comment: Well, you could probably do what Divakar suggested, but in a "blockwise" fashion. That way you would still have 2 `for` loops on the outside, but the actual computation will be done with the more efficient `bsxfun`. Also, if you don't need the precision of `double` maybe try to convert you matrices into a smaller datatype (e.g `single`) - that could help with memory issues too...

Comment: @mining Check out the just added **Approach #3**?  Also, converting to `single` could be looked into if *some* drop in precision won't bother you.

Comment: @Dev-iL Thank you! Implemented that and seems like its giving a huge speedup!

Comment: You're very welcome - I'm glad to know that my ideas not only make sense to me :). More importantly, a lot can be learned from the `bsxfun` deep magic presented in this answer.

Comment: @Dev-iL The runtimes and speedups thus obtained are magic indeed!

Comment: @Divakar, Thank you! I'm very appreciated for your continuing endeavors to help improving these solutions and benchmarks! I couldn't imagine so much faster speed up! The solution is really amazing! Thank you!

Comment: @mining Awesome! Actually I learnt a lot myself from this particular question, so thank you too for bringing it onto Stackoverflow!

Comment: @Dev-iL, Thank you very much for your valuable hints to get better solution!

Comment: @Divakar, your solutions really means a lot to me! I learned a lot from your solutions, although I couldn't still absolutely understand your code as I lack of the experiences on these commands, e.g. `bsxfun` or `permute`. Your solutions give me a very impressive insight to these commands! I'll learn more about these basic commands in the future. Thank you!